# How to remove key from input?

Tags: laravel-5.6

I am passing JWT token in request object for verification. After verifying JWT, I want to remove the token key from input otherwise it reaches model and generates error.

One way is to use something like $request->except('token') but I have to write this everywhere. 
Second way is to use a middleware to remove this key:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class InputCheck
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $request->request->remove('token');

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

The above statement is not removing token. Can't find anything on how to remove key from $request. Middleware is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the except method in the middleware:

```
$response = $request->except(['token']);

return $next($response);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#retrieving-input under Retrieving A Portion Of The Input Data